# Posting to wordpress from other website

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'm making a php website that should be able to post to wordpress blog (on the same server but in another dir).
I've seen that it's possible with XML-RPC, however, I need to add custom terms/taxonomies and "categories" and other meta data. 
Does anyone know how can I do this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution was easier that what I was trying to do.
Since (as I've mentioned) the two applications are on the same server in sibling folders. I just included wp-config.php and wp-load.php and I got all wordpress functionality from my application. so there was no need for XML-RPC which is quite a pain in the a$$.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Wordpress JSON plugin.  It exposes a full REST API of your wordpress content: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/  The full details of the API exposed are under the 'other notes' section.

If you're trying to use wordpress as just a CMS and not a magic-site-building tool, use REST not XML-RPC.  IT will be easier when you're trying to pull your content to things like a javascript AJAX request.

With XML-RPC to access wordpress specific functionality you'll probably  have to register your own function calls outside the default supported APIs. WordPress currently support the Blogger API, metaWeblog API, Movable Type API, and the Pingback API. See the note in the comment section about the WP set of xml-rpc functions as well.

If you decide to go the route of the stone age and use XML-RPC, here's a link overviewing what you'll have to do to add the functionality I think you want: http://kovshenin.com/2010/custom-xml-rpc-methods-in-wordpress/

Comment: Although support for those legacy APIs exist, they have been largely superseeded by the [XML-RPC_WordPress_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API) for which there exist functions for nearly all of the typical actions you need to perform, including editing and adding taxonomies, post meta, etc.

Comment: @userabuser True, but they still lack simple things like: getPostBySlug.  I've felt that worpress has always treated XML-RPC as a way to facilitate posting into wordpress via 3rd party apps, not pulling stuff out to use elsewhere

Comment: I'm not a big fan of external plugins, I'm looking for a way to make it in a "normal" way. but thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @BaseemNajjar unfortunately wordpress does not provide a 'normal' way to do what you want in any way except via the wp-admin page--see the XML-RPC link in my post to creating your own worpress function to if you want.